# Match with multiple criteria using array

Tags: arrays, vba, match

I need to define the best match based on multiple conditions for a long range of items
The range is based on a high number of rows (around 5000 at least) and on many columns: especially, Family, Pivot Code, Selection, Quantity, Reference 1, Price 1, Reference 2, Price 2,... 
The columns of references can change (there can be 2 or nth references)
For each combination of Family and Pivot Code, I need to find which is the row with the max quantity and with a reference price 1
If  there is no Family/Pivot Combination with a reference price 1, I will look if there is a reference price 2, etc etc
If there  is no Family/Pivot Combination with any reference price I will look for the highest quantity despite the reference price, etc etc
In order to make less complex I split a huge formula in many formula like this one

```
 IFERROR(MATCH(1;($A$2:$A$20=$M2)*($B$2:$B$20=$N2)*($F$2:$F$20=LARGE(IF($A$2:$A$20=$M2;IF($B$2:$B$20=$N2;IF($H$2:$H$20<>"";IF($F$2:$F$20<>"";$F$2:$F$20))));1));0)&"-Reference";FALSE)
```

My problem is that due to the high number of rows, applying the formula in excel sheet will take too much time, as well as applying Evaluate function. 
Then, I wanted to try with an array, but I am not able to find the right way to make it work. Here the partial code I created until now (other 'if' conditions are still missing and I had to add also Countif function that slow down the process as well)

```
Sub comparearray()
Dim test As Boolean
Dim familyrng, pivotrng, xrng, qtyrng, ref1rng, ref2rng, relrefrng, rangeM, rangeN, Ranges
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim c As Range
Dim formtest
Dim Count
Dim a, b
Dim i, rws, CustMax, k As Long
Dim Max As Long
Dim t As Single


Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
ws.Select
lr = ws.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row
lr1 = ws.Range("M1048576").End(xlUp).Row
'lc = .cells(20, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

familyrng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(lr, 1)).Value
Set familyrange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(lr, 1))
pivotrng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(lr, 2)).Value
Set pivotrange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(lr, 2))
xrng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(2, 3), Cells(lr, 3)).Value
Set xrange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(2, 3), Cells(lr, 3))
qtyrng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(2, 4), Cells(lr, 4)).Value
Set qtyrange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(2, 4), Cells(lr, 4))
ref1rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(2, 6), Cells(lr, 6)).Value
Set ref1range = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(2, 6), Cells(lr, 6))
ref2rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(2, 8), Cells(lr, 8)).Value
Set ref2range = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(2, 8), Cells(lr, 8))
relrefrng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(2, 9), Cells(lr, 9)).Value
Set relrefrange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(2, 9), Cells(lr, 9))

rangeM = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(2, 13), Cells(lr1, 13)).Value
rangeN = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(2, 14), Cells(lr1, 14)).Value
Ranges = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(2, 15), Cells(lr1, 15)).Value


t = Timer

rws = UBound(familyrng, 1)
rws1 = UBound(rangeM, 1)
rownum = 0
For k = 1 To rws1
Cust = rangeM(k, 1)
Cust1 = rangeN(k, 1)
Cust3 = Ranges(k, 1)

If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(familyrange, Cust, pivotrange, Cust1, qtyrange, "<>""", ref1range, "<>""") > 0 Then
'Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(familyrng, Cust, pivotrng, Cust1, qtyrng, "<>""", ref1rng, "<>""") > 0
For i = LBound(familyrng) To UBound(familyrng)

    If familyrng(i, 1) = Cust And pivotrng(i, 1) = Cust1 And qtyrng(i, 1) <> "" And ref1rng(i, 1) <> "" Then
    If qtyrng(i, 1) > CustMax Then
    CustMax = qtyrng(i, 1) And rownum = i
    'Debug.Print CustMax
    End If
    End If
    Next i
    Cells(k + 1, 15) = rws & "-Reference"
Else
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(familyrange, Cust, pivotrange, Cust1, ref1range, "<>""", xrange, "x") > 0 Then
For i = 1 To rws

    If familyrng(i, 1) = Cust And pivotrng(i, 1) = Cust1 And qtyrng(i, 1) <> "" And ref1rng(i, 1) <> "" And xrng = "x" Then
    rownum = i
    End If
    Next i
    Cells(k + 1, 15) = rownum & "No Runner-refetitor"

End If
End If
Next k
Debug.Print Format(Timer -t, "0.000000000 secs")
End Sub
```

Could you tell if my approach is the fastest and, if so, how can I define which is the row  number of the best match cell (in my code *‘rownum = i’*)

Comment: Ok. Some remarks: If I read it correctly, your table has variable dimensions, rows = number of entries and columns = family+pivot+selection+quantity + N*(reference + ref_price). As I understand, you a priori don't know N for each entry, therefore it would make sence to dynamically define the whole table as a range and use indices to access both rows and columns. That would also safe you a lot of rows in code. Regarding efficiency, using WorksheetFunctions is almost always inefficient compared to VBA functions.

Comment: As an efficient procedure i would propose:

1) Read whole table to array
2) Extract a unique list of family/pivot combinations
3) For each combination create a list of rows that correspond
4) For each combination loop through the list with initial variables qty = 0 refNo = 1000
5) If an entry in the list has a quantity larger then the variable qty and a reference price of order <= refNo replace the variable value and safe the row number
6) As a result you have the best row for each combination